# Div tag events in jquery

Tags: jquery

What are the div tag events in jQuery ? I need to calculate the length of the div for that i wrote these code .

```
function drop(ev)
{

 ev.preventDefault();
 var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
 ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true)); 

     var n = $( "#div2" ).length;
        alert(n);


}
```

But every time it showing answer as one . when ever i drop more images it must specify the how many images are in div . Will u help me wwhat event i have to write to get this answer .

Comment: Where exactly do you define the id `#div2` and how is that related to the contents of `ev`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when ever i drop more images it must specify the how many images are in div

I believe you're looking for

```
var n = $( "#div2 img" ).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

To find `count` of images in `div` you can use [descendant selector (“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)to find descendant of type `img` in the `div` having id `div2`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SXSNW/1/)**

```
$("#div2 img").length;
```

> Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

When you use this `$( "#div2" )` it means - element with ID="div2". and as you know there could be only 1 such element because id is unique. 
For getting all the divs use  `$( "div" )` for getting all the elements wit div2 class use `$( ".div2" )`

Answer (score 0):

To get the length of images img tag inside of div i.e div2 :

```
var len = $("div2 > img").length;
```